# пользовательские переменные mysql в разделе FROM

Tags: mysql, user-variables

```
select @tab1 := concat("log_sessions_",year(now()), month(now()));
-- @tab1 = log_sessions_201912
select *
from log_sessions_201912
where date_format(hour,"%d%.%m.%Y") = date_format(now(),"%d%.%m.%Y")
```

хотелось бы использовать @tab1 во from, чтобы запрос менялся месяц от месяца "сам", но по простому это не работает.

можете что-нибудь посоветовать без генерации запроса внешними скриптами?

Comment: *where date_format(hour,"%d%.%m.%Y") = date_format(now(),"%d%.%m.%Y")* Тормозить будет - это же фуллскан. ``WHERE `hour` >= CURRENT_DATE AND `hour` < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY``.

Comment: так то - да, но это не все условия по дате-времени и так оно вроде бы легче читаться будет через пару лет когда заново туда посмотреть возможно надо будет.

Comment: *так оно вроде бы легче читаться будет через пару лет* Вот это твоё, с форматами, легче читать, чем моё, которое даже понимать не надо, достаточно на русский перевести? не, серьёзно?

Comment: вне всякого сомнения шаблон узнаётся быстрее вычисляемого выражения. даже на родном языке.
 но религиозные вопросы обсуждать бесмыслено.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вот же, в документации (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) прям есть пример: prepare, execute.

```
set @tab1 := concat("log_sessions_",year(now()), month(now()));
set @sql = concat(
    'select * from ',
    @tab1,
    ' where date_format(hour,"%d%.%m.%Y") = date_format(now(),"%d%.%m.%Y")'
);
prepare st from @sql;
execute st;
```